# Detecting when a hasMany property has been populated with no results

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

What I'm trying to do seems simple but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

I am using Emberjs 2.8.

I have the following model with an `async: true` property:

```
models/my-model.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  childModels: DS.hasMany('otherModel', {async: true})
});
```

I have a component that displays one of these models:

```
/components/my-component.js

import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   theModel: // model of type my-model here
})
```

It's possible that `my-model.childModels` does not have any records. What I would like to do is in the template display a "no children found" message if that is the case but I only want to do this **after** the async call to the server is made and returned an empty response. So I would want the template to look something like this:

```
templates/components/my-component.hbs

<div>
{{#if theModel.childModels.length == 0}}
   // display message saying there are no children
{{else}}
   {{#each theModel.childModels as |child}}
      // do something
   {{/each}}
{{/if}}
</div>
```

The tricky part is knowing if the relationship has already populated from the server. I can't just check for `.length == 0` because that is true before the async call is made and I don't want the DOM toggling back and forth unnecessarily. What I need is something like `theModel.childModels.isLoaded` but after looking through the docs I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Could anyone suggest a way to do this? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: Can you post what request does it make when accessing `theModel.get('childModels')`? Because as far as I know either you provided ids with `parentModel` so you already know how many children is there or it doesn't work.

Comment: @Keo the request is to it's own endpoint and would look like `/api/the_model/{pk}/children` - not all responses require ids, it can just be a link to where to find the resources

Comment: Oh, right. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I feel silly now because I found the answer and it was in the docs afterall. The `PromiseManyArray` uses the [PromiseProxyMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html) which does have a `isPending` property. So I can just create a computed property like so:

```
  childModelsEmpty: Ember.computed('theModel.childModels', function () {
    return !this.get('theModel.childModels.isPending') && this.get('theModel.childModels.length') === 0;
  }),
```

That will tell me if the server has been hit and an empty response was returned.